# Counting calls to certain methods of a class and of any subclass

Tags: python, metaclass

I have a generic class that users are supposed to subclass in order to implement certain methods. There can be subclasses several levels deep. Something like

```
class Thing(object):
    def fun(self, *args, **kwargs):
        raise NotImplementedError()

class Bell(Thing):
    def fun(self):
        return 1

class Whistle(Bell):
    def fun(self):
        return super(Whistle, self).fun() + 1
```

I would like to count the number of times that `fun()` is called when any subclass of `Thing` is used. Because decorators aren't inherited, and because I don't want users to have to remember to decorate their `fun()` method, my understanding is that metaclasses are the way to go. So I wrote

```
class CountCalls(type):

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        attrs["_original_fun"] = attrs["fun"]
        attrs["fun"] = countcalls(attrs["_original_fun"])
        return super(CountCalls, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
```

where `countcalls` is the classic decorator to count the number of calls:

```
def countcalls(fn):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        wrapper.ncalls += 1
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    wrapper.ncalls = 0
    wrapper.__name__ = fn.__name__
    wrapper.__doc__ = fn.__doc__
    return wrapper
```

and changed the definition of `Thing` to

```
class Thing(object):

    __metaclass__ = CountCalls

    def fun(self, *args, **kwargs):
        raise NotImplementedError()
```

**Problem**: That works, but it has the unintended side effect of incrementing the number of calls counter of *all* instances when the `fun()` method of *any*  instance is called:

```
>>> b1 = Bell()
>>> b2 = Bell()
>>> b1.fun.ncalls, b2.fun.ncalls
(0, 0)
>>> b1.fun()
1
>>> b1.fun.ncalls, b2.fun.ncalls
(1, 1)
```

**Question**: How do I count the number of calls to `fun()` on a per-instance basis? It feels like I should be implementing `__init__` instead of `__new__` in the metaclass, but so far I've not found the correct syntax. For example, using

```
def __init__(self, name, bases, attrs):
    attrs["_original_fun"] = attrs["fun"]
    attrs["fun"] = countcalls(attrs["_original_fun"])
    super(CountCalls, self).__init__(name, bases, attrs)
```

yields

```
>>> b = Bell()
>>> b.fun.ncalls
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'ncalls'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can skip the metaclass by changing your inheritance pattern a little:

```
class Thing(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.fun_calls = 0

    def fun(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.fun_calls += 1
        self._fun(*args, **kwargs)

    def _fun(self, *args, **kwargs):
        raise NotImplementedError()
```

Then just override `_fun` in your subclasses. This gets you per-instance automatic counting, and it's (imo) cleaner and more understandable than a metaclass implementation.

Comment: Elegant, simple, pythonic. Best way to do it IMO.

Comment: I agree that is it the simplest way to do it, although it doesn't provide a way to automate counting the number of calls to every method defined which is probably why the OP is using a metaclass in the first place.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate the simplicity of this approach. I used to do something similar, but abandoned it because it wasn't user friendly to have to implement a method with a name that doesn't directly reflect the functionality you're implementing.

Answer (score 0):

In order to keep track of the calls for each instance instead of each function, you would need the variable keeping track of it to be on the instance, something like:

```
def countcalls(fn):
    def wrapper(self,*args, **kwargs):
        self._calls_dict[wrapper]+=1
        return fn(self,*args, **kwargs)
    wrapper.__name__ = fn.__name__
    wrapper.__doc__ = fn.__doc__
    return wrapper
```

although you need some way of initializing the dictionary for the first call:

```
import collections

def countcalls(fn):
    def wrapper(self,*args, **kwargs):
        if not hasattr(self,"_calls_dict"):
            self._calls_dict = collections.defaultdict(int)
        self._calls_dict[wrapper.__name__]+=1
        return fn(self,*args, **kwargs)
    wrapper.__name__ = fn.__name__
    wrapper.__doc__ = fn.__doc__
    return wrapper
```

although please note that this will fall apart if this decorator is applied to `classmethod`s or `staticmethod`s so be careful how you implement this.

This also complicates how to retrieve the number of calls but it can be done fairly easily with a seperate function:

```
from types import MethodType

def get_calls(method):
    if not isinstance(method,MethodType):
        raise TypeError("must pass bound method as argument")

    func = method.__func__
    inst = method.__self__

    dct = getattr(inst,"_calls_dict",None)
    if dct is None or func not in dct:
        return 0 #maybe raise an error instead?
    else:
        return dct[func]
```